# How to get the while loop to recognise it is the end of the file

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, readline, eof

I have a text file with data that represents 
Line 1
name, email, phone
Line 2
address
Line 3 
is an integer that says how many friends are listed.
Line 4 ~ n
Each line consists of a name

I have been able to get each line with

```
line = infile.readline()
```

I have a problem when I get to the end of the file.

It wants to loop around again as if it does not recognise the end of the file

```
infile = open(filename, "r")
lines = infile.readlines()

with open(filename) as infile:  
        line = infile.readline()
        count = 1
        while line:
            thisProfile = profile.Profile()          
            if count > 1:
                line = infile.readline()
                count += 1
            word = line.split()
            thisProfile.set_given_name(word[0])
            thisProfile.set_last_name(word[0])
            thisProfile.set_email_name(word[0])
            thisProfile.set_phone(word[0])

            ## LINE 2 -- ADDRESS
            line = infile.readline()
            count += 1
            thisProfile.set_address(line)

             ## LINE 3 -- GET FRIEND COUNT
             line = infile.readline()
             count += 1

             ## get all the friends and add them to the friends_list
             friendCount = int(line)
             thisProfile.set_number_friends(friendCount)
             friendList = []
             if friendCount > 0:
                 for allfreinds in range(0,friendCount):
                     line = infile.readline()
                     count += 1
                     friendList.append(line)
                 thisProfile.set_friends_list(friendList)
```

**friends.txt**

```
John Doe john.doe@hotmail.com 123456789
1 alltheway ave
1
Jane Doe
Paul Andrews paul.andrews@gmail.com 987654321
69 best street
0
Jane Doe jane.doe@facebook.com 159753456
1 alltheway ave
2
John Doe
Paul Andrews
```

Comment: I updated the title, my specific problem is END_OF_FILE .. it wants to loop back to the begining.  Is there another way to stop this happening other than testing at the begining if lineCount <= totalLines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readline()` method returns an empty string only when EOF is reached per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), so you can add a condition to check if `line` is empty (not truthy) right after you call `readline()`:

```
with open(filename) as infile:  
    while True:
        line = infile.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        thisProfile = profile.Profile()          
        word = line.split()
        thisProfile.set_given_name(word[0])
```

Alternatively, you can use the file object as an iterator with a `for` loop instead:

```
with open(filename) as infile:  
    for line in infile:
        thisProfile = profile.Profile()          
        word = line.split()
        thisProfile.set_given_name(word[0])
```

Comment: using the second suggestion I am skipping the first line

Comment: I just had to remove --> line = infile.readline() after the loop is called .. TY for your help crew :-)

Comment: Please make sure you remove your first `line = infile.readline()` if you are to use the second method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
for line in infiles.readline():
    *code*
```

instead of the while loop.